# How to find the eigen values of the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given the matrix
>
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 5&1&1&1&1&1\\1&5&1&1&1&1\\1&1&5&1&1&1\\1&1&1&4&1&0\\1&1&1&1&4&0\\1&1&1&0&0&3
> \end{bmatrix}
>
> find its eigen values(preferably by elementary row/column operations).

Since I don't know any other method other than elementary operations to find eigen values so I tried writing the characteristic polynomial of the matrix  which is follows:

> \begin{bmatrix}
> x-5&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1\\-1&x-5&-1&-1&-1&-1\\-1&-1&x-5&-1&-1&-1\\-1&-1&-1&x-4&-1&0\\-1&-1&-1&-1&x-4&0\\-1&-1&-1&0&0&x-3
> \end{bmatrix}

Using $R1=R1-(R2+R3+R4+R5+R6)$

> \begin{bmatrix}
> x&-x+8&-x+8&-x+6&-x+6&-x+4\\-1&x-5&-1&-1&-1&-1\\-1&-1&x-5&-1&-1&-1\\-1&-1&-1&x-4&-1&0\\-1&-1&-1&-1&x-4&0\\-1&-1&-1&0&0&x-3
> \end{bmatrix}

Comment: Since they have the same determinant, I would start with the negative of your last matrix. It's easier to think without all these minus signs.

Comment: Sigh. The matrix is symmetric, which is emphasized in the mention of row/column operations. Where did you get the problem and what book are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your matrix $A$. Let $B=A-3I$.
$$
B=\pmatrix{
2&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&2&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&2&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&0\\
1&1&1&1&1&0\\
1&1&1&0&0&0}.
$$
$B$ has two identical columns (4 and 5), so we try to remove one of them. Perform the column operation $C5\leftarrow C5-C4$ followed by the inverse row operation $R4\leftarrow R4+R5$:
$$
\pmatrix{
2&1&1&1&0&1\\
1&2&1&1&0&1\\
1&1&2&1&0&1\\
2&2&2&2&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&0&0}.
$$
We now get a zero eigenvalue at the $(5,5)$-th position. Remove the fifth row and column:
$$
\pmatrix{
2&1&1&1&1\\
1&2&1&1&1\\
1&1&2&1&1\\
2&2&2&2&0\\
1&1&1&0&0}.
$$
The first two rows in this matrix sans $I_2$ are identical, so we try to remove a duplicate row. Do $R1\leftarrow R1-R2$ and then the inverse row operation $C2\leftarrow C2+C1$:
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&0&0&0\\
1&3&1&1&1\\
1&2&2&1&1\\
2&4&2&2&0\\
1&2&1&0&0}.
$$
We now get another eigenvalue $1$ at the top-left position. Remove the first row and column:
$$
\pmatrix{
3&1&1&1\\
2&2&1&1\\
4&2&2&0\\
2&1&0&0}.
$$
Do $R1\leftarrow R1-R2$ and $C2\leftarrow C2+C1$ again:
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&0&0\\
2&4&1&1\\
4&6&2&0\\
2&3&0&0}.
$$
Now we get another eigenvalue $1$ at the top-left position. Remove the first row and column:
$$
\pmatrix{
4&1&1\\
6&2&0\\
3&0&0}.
$$
We may now calculate its characteristic polynomial by hand. It is
\begin{align}
&(x-4)(x-2)x - 6x -3(x-2)\\
=\,&x^3 - 6x^2 + 8x - 6x - 3x + 6\\
=\,&x^3 - 6x^2 - x + 6\\
=\,&(x-6)(x^2-1).
\end{align}
The eigenvalues of this matrix are $6,1,-1$. Therefore the eigenvalues of $B$ are $0,1,1,6,1,-1$ and the eigenvalues of $A=B+3I$ are $3,4,4,9,4,2$.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial $\chi_t$ of this matrix can be factored nicely, i.e.,
$$
\chi_t(A)=(t - 2)(t - 3)(t - 4)^3(t - 9).
$$
So the six eigenvalues are $2,3,4,4,4,9$.

Comment: How did you manage to factor $\chi_t$ so quickly?

Comment: For the linear factors we can use the "rational root test". In this case, we are already done after this.

Comment: I suppose. Nice solution. (+1)

Comment: Thank you for the compliment:)

Comment: The rational root test might apply once you *know* the polynomial. The question was how to *get* the polynomial, wasn't it?

Comment: @Christoph The polynomial is computed by the determinant: $\det(t\cdot I-A)=t^6 - 26t^5 + 267t^4 - 1402t^3 + 3992t^2 - 5856t + 3456$.

Comment: Pretty sure OP was looking for an efficient calculation of that $6\times 6$ determinant by hand...

Comment: @Christoph There is even a general formula for the determinant of such matrices, if you subsitute the $0$ entries by $1$; a modification will reduce to that formula.

Comment: @DietrichBurde; Can you please show by a step-step procedure how you did it?

Comment: @DietrichBurde,I never asked for the answer.It can be done with a software also.Please show me how to do it by hand

Comment: @Christoph;You are right

Comment: @New_User I have something that really uses the fact that the matrix is symmetric, with combined row/column operations as specified. Where did you get the problem, what book/notes are being used, what is being studied in the chapter leading up to this?

Comment: @WillJagy; I am reading a book on Matrices and Determinants,the notes before the problem are elementary row and column operations

Comment: @New_User I have now spent some time on this, and the following is not obvious: in what way does your book say that you can find **the separate eigenvalues** using row and column operations?

Comment: I really don't know @WillJagy